# Full text search is not working if search for characters anywhere in the string

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have created a full text search index on ClientReference column but it doesn't work if i want to search for characters appearing any where in the string.

String = ' abcdef '

This won't work;

```
SELECT * FROM Proposals 
WHERE CONTAINS([ClientReference], '"*bc*"')
```

But it works if i use prefix.

```
SELECT * FROM Proposals 
WHERE CONTAINS([ClientReference], '"a*"')
```

[image]

[image]

**ADDED**

Someone has just mentioned that "it is not possible, You can only search based on word but not search based on alphabets within a word."

So why the following works and looks for '223' any where in the string?

```
 select ClientReference1 from ClientReferences 
 where CONTAINS([ClientReference1], '"*223*"')
```

[image]

Comment: you are using a prefix_term as mentioned here it will fetch data starting with those alphabets or words http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx, thats the reason c* works but not re*

Comment: How to accomplish this ClientReference LIKE '%re%' with full text search?

Comment: That is not possible, You can only search based on word but not search based on alphabets within a word.

Comment: Can you show the full query?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have lots of text and/or lots of rows (millions+), you may be better served just using `LIKE` instead of `CONTAINS`.

```
SELECT * FROM Proposals  WHERE ClientReference LIKE '%re%'
```

Comment: Is there a reason for full text search? The amount of text in that field is small... maybe just use `like`? `SELECT * FROM Proposals 
WHERE ClientReference LIKE '%re%'`

Comment: i don't mind using like as we won't have millions+ rows in this new table but i still like to know why full text search is not working.

Comment: You certainly should not be putting the `*` after 're'. Not sure why changing that doesn't work though.